# Creating table that omits certain values

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I want to run a function of the form

```
Table[i*j,{i,-5,5},{j,-5,5}]
```

but I want to omit all the values of $|i|\leq1$ and $|j|\leq1$. In other words, how do I create my 2D grid of values that doesn't contain the box of length 2 centered at the origin.

How would I write this in a general form rather than making the table by hand?

Comment: You mean you want to skip $i=-1,0,1$ and $j=-1,0,1$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to skip the 9 pairs ${i,j}$ where $i=-1,0,1$, $j=-1,0,1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And just for fun, here is another approach

```
Flatten[Table[If[Abs[i]<= 1 || Abs[j] <=1, Nothing[], i*j], {i, -5, 5}, {j, -5, 5}], {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: My question was probably not sufficiently clear. This is what I was looking for but exchanging the Or ( || ) for an And ( && ). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to explicitly set the range for the variables:

```
ran = Select[Range[-5, 5], Abs[#] > 1 &];
Table[i*j, {i, ran}, {j, ran}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one to try to get me to 10K.

```
With[{r = Join[#, -Reverse@#] &@Range[-5, -2]}, Table[i j, {i, r}, {j, r}]]
```